# How to have an event trigger every time a user presses a key in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keydown

First of all, I'm new to Javascript. I would like to have an event repeat itself every time a user presses a key in Javascript. See the sample code below:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 39) {
            document.write('Right was pressed');
        }
    })
</script>
```

When this code is run and the right arrow key is pressed, the statement is only printed once. I would like to have the event register multiple times, as many times as the user presses the key. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` for this. Instead, you should mutate the content of whatever element you're targeting; if the whole page, then use `document.body`. You can add text with `document.body.textContent += "new content"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is fired every time you press the key (and repeated if you hold the key down), but `document.write()` will every time override the content so it looks like nothing change, you could use `innerHTML` instead (just to see the effect) :

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 39) {
    //Not recommended as 'T.J. Crowder' mentioned in the comment
    document.body.innerHTML += 'Right was pressed <br>';
  }
})
```

You could use `console.log()` to debug and make sure the event was invoked :

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 39) {
    console.log('Right was pressed');
  }
})
```

Comment: *"will every time override the content"* No, only the first time after parsing of the page is complete. Then, it will keep adding to the document until you call `document.close`. But `document.write` was almost certainly the problem and doing something else (as you have above) is the solution (though I'd advocate *never* using `+=` with `innerHTML`, certainly not when showing someone how to do something).

Comment: It worked properly when i wrote to the body as you &  @squint suggested. I was also testing the code with console.log and alert but these would only display once which gave me the impression the event was not being registered more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it indeed triggered multiple times. The problem is document.write would clear the DOM.

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly1j01nr/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Ly1j01nr) works well for me.

script:

```
var counter = 0;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 39){
    ++counter;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Key downed " + counter;
  }
});
```

html:

```
<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Comment: This has [already been posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40947897/157247). No need to duplicate existing answers. When you realize you've just duplicated an existing answer, use "delete" to delete the duplicate.